# How do i delete data from my ASP.net database?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to manually delete ALL data from my databse in a Table in ASP.net.

This is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Ask under the right tag for starters. This is [tag:asp-classic] not  [tag:asp.net].

Comment: Try using `DELETE FROM TableName`

Comment: Where do i write "DELETE FROM Table" ?

Comment: Can't you just select all rows and press Delete on your keyboard?

Comment: Oh is it possible just doing so i did not know that thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Server Explorer you can right click your table and choose "New Query".

A query window will appear where you can type sql queries, for instance

```
DELETE FROM Table
```

Another option if you are viewing the table data is to press Ctrl A on your keyboard and then press the delete key. A question dialog appears with "You are about to delete 3 Row(s)." If you click Yes, all data will be deleted from the table.